# directory not available when i turned into root user

Tags: git, vim, terminal

I cloned the [scrooloose/nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) plugin inside my

`./vim/bundle` directory 
using the command

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
```

and set up my `vimrc` file, everything is fine but when i turned into root user using command `sudo su`
nerdtree directory is now not available.

What should i do so that it becomes available? The problem is not only with nerdtree but with every plugin I cloned.

**edit**

I found one solution for it but not the one I needed.
I cloned it two times one using

-`sudo git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`

and another time using

-`sudo su`

-`git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`

This solved my problem.

Comment: you can execute `ls ` when you enter in `sudo su` and you will se that there are not any `.vimrc` `.vim` file folders

Comment: my .vim folder is present and i can enter into it....also my vimrc file is in /etc/vim and it is also present.

Comment: but they need to be in `~` home directory no ?

Comment: My vimrc file is always in /etc/vim

Answer (score 0):

Note where you are cloning the vim bundles to: `~/.vim/bundle/`. It looks like you are trying to force vim to be the same for all users by editing the `/etc/vim/vimrc`. In this case, your bundles would also need to be in that directory. I.e., try cloning to `/etc/vim/bundle/nerdtree` instead of to `~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`. The instructions you are following assume you are only changing vim for your user instead of every user on the system.

Comment: Even plugin manager (i am using Vundle) is cloning the repo in 
 ~/.vim/bundle/

Comment: because you are telling it to when you run `sudo git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`. you are specifying where it should clone to.

Answer (score 0):

Any command `sudo command ~/path` works with your user's `$HOME`, not root. Example:

```
$ echo ~
/home/phd
$ sudo echo ~
[sudo] password for phd: 
/home/phd
```

It's because `~` is interpreted by the user's shell before running `sudo`.

To overcome use absolute paths: `sudo command /root/path`:

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdtree.git /root/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
```

Comment: using this the directory is available only for root user.

Comment: I use `sudo su` to become root.

Comment: Then using `/root` directory is ok.

Comment: No using this the directory is available only when I am root.

Answer (score 0):

The `.vim` directory of root and any user is different...

Of root is located in

`/root/.vim`

And for user like "ramesh" is located in

`/home/ramesh/.vim`

So cloning into one does not reflects into other.